# Find a coordinate `b` such that 4 points$v_1(1,-1,0), v_2(2, -1, 1), v_3(-1, -1, b), v_4(1, 1- b, 0)$ on the same plain

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This question was originaly in my midterm in calculus 2, my professor says I'm wrong (and gave me 0 out of 20 points), when I think I'm right.

It's a bit long question, but please read it.

If Im right, I'd love if you can justify my answer.

If Im wrong, I'd love if you can explain me where I've wrong.

Original question:

> Question 2: (20 points)
>
> find a value for $b$ such that points $p_1(1,-1,0), p_2(2, -1, 1), p_3(-1, -1, b), p_4(1, 1- b, 0)$ on the same plain.

My Answer:

> We know that $n$ vectors $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ are on the same plain $\iff$ $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ lineary independent.
>
> Take points $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^4$ and  represent them as vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^4 = \{\vec{(0,0,0)p_i}\}_{i=1}^4$ (vectors from $(0,0,0)$ to $p_i$).
>
> Take $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^4$ and check whether they're linearly independent.
>
> Put $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^4$ in a matrix:

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-1&0&0\\
        2&-1&1&0\\
        -1&-1&b&0\\
        1&{1-b}&0&0
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

> eliminate the matrix using [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) in the hope to get a `"full zero"` row which tells us this vector space is linearly independent.

$$ 
\left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-1&0&0\\
        2&-1&1&0\\
        -1&-1&b&0\\
        1&{1-b}&0&0
      \end{array}
    \right]_{r_2 = r_2 - r_1} = 
\left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-1&0&0\\
        1&0&1&0\\
        -1&-1&b&0\\
        1&{1-b}&0&0
      \end{array}
    \right]_{r_3 = r_3 + r_2} = 
\left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-1&0&0\\
        2&-1&1&0\\
        0&-1&{b+1}&0\\
        1&{1-b}&0&0
      \end{array}
    \right]_{r_4 = r_4 - r_1} = 
\left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-1&0&0\\
        2&-1&1&0\\
        0&-1&{b+1}&0\\
        0&{1-b+1}&0&0
      \end{array}
    \right] .
$$

> We can multiply any line by any Real number scalar and the independency will stay the same. take $m \in R$ and set $r_4 = mr_4$.
>
> But we can later multiply by $\frac{1}{m}$, than the change will only come with a different sign. so the other `b` can be found by multiply be $-1$.

$$
\left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-1&0&0\\
        2&-1&1&0\\
        0&-1&{b+1}&0\\
        0&{1-b+1}&0&0
      \end{array}
    \right]_{r_4 = (-1)r_4} = \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-1&0&0\\
        2&-1&1&0\\
        0&-1&{b+1}&0\\
        0&{-1+b-1}&0&0
      \end{array}
    \right].
$$

So,  in order that points $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^4$ will be on the same plain, this matrix representation needs at least on `"full zero"` row.

Hence $b = 2$ or $b =-2$.

My professor has got the same answer, but in a different way:

> Solution:
>
> Take the plain equition passes through 3 points: $p_1, p_2, p_3$.
>
> We'll create 2 vectors:
>
> $\vec(AB) = (1, -2, 1)$
>
> $\vec(AC) = (-2, 0, b)$
>
> Calculate the normal vector:
>
> $\vec(N) = \vec(AB)\times\vec(AC) = (-2b, -2-b, -4)$
>
> A plain equation given by $p_1x + p_2y + p_3z = p_4$ as $A = -2b, B = -2-b, C= -4$, i.e. $2bx + (2+b)y+4z = D$.
>
> Plug $p_1$ and we'll get the constant $D$: $2b*1-(2+b)*1+4*0 = D.
>
> Hence $D = b-2$. Hence plain equation: 2bx+(2+b)y+4z = b-2.
>
> We've found plain equation contains 3 points: $p_1, p_2, p_3$.
>
> In order that D(1,1 - b, 0) also be on this plain, it have to fit the plain equation, so plug it into the equation: $2b + (2+b)(1-b) + 4*0 = b-2.

Again, It's really important to me if you can justify my answer if I'm right,

Or explain me my mistake.

Thanks in advance!!!

> $\implies 2 - b^2 = 2 \implies b = 2$ or $b = (-2)$

Comment: Anyone to help me?

Comment: Why did you write that last bit about $2-b^2 = 2$? (Also notice that it's incorrect because $2-b^2 = 2 \Rightarrow b^2 = 0$). Also why do you think you need two solutions for b? The question only asks for one. In regards to methods, I think you defined your matrix incorrectly. Recall for the definition of linear independence you would start with $a(1,-1,0) + b(2,-1,1) + c(-1,-1,b) + d(1,1-b,0) = (0,0,0)$. So you were working with the transpose of the matrix you needed. Using the correct one, you'll notice you have linear dependence regardless of your value for b (more unknowns then equations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read through it all but realized an error you made at the beginning.

You state that we know that n vectors in the same plane if and only if they are linearly independent.  But this isn't true.  Consider the xy plane.  Now think about two vectors:  $(1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.  They are the same vector, and so they are linearly dependent.  They also both lie in the xy plane.  Thus, your statement is violated.